# IndexedDB in Metro, domain changed after running WACK tool?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, indexeddb

I am trying to get this IndexedDB stuff working in a Metro (Windows 8) app, using JS.

I thought I was good, but then I ran the WACK tool a couple of times, just to see if I ran into any issues.

After these tests the IndexedDB.open call no longer opens my database (which has 7 entries in it) instead it fires onupgradeneeded, and gives me a blank (new) database (since I create an object store in the onupgradeneeded handler).

I did not change my version number, I did not change the database name. So I am guessing the applications domain somehow changed during the WACK tests.

Does anyone now how to get my database domain back?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things the WACK test probably does is doing a fresh install of the app checking if everything goes fine. So when the app is installed for the first time you have to provide a creation of the database, this is done in the onupgradeneeded event.

I think you forgot to provide this, and that is why he creates a new blank database. Instead of a new database with the required structure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Everything worked fine until I tested in the WACK tool? My records were stored and I could retrieve them. So the database must have been created (I would guess). I create the object store in the onupgradeneeded handler, and have done so the entire time.

Comment: Did you change the name of your app? I think the name of the app defines the domain. And the databases inside the indexeddb are domain dependend. Maybe this is one of the reasons?

Comment: I didn't change a thing, which is why it puzzles me. Of course the WACK tool adds packages to the AppPackages directory, and they get named via the packaging versioning in the manifest file, but even changing that back to 1.0.0.0  doesn't recover my domain. I just spent the entire morning rewriting my persistent storing to a flat json file on the disk (it's way easier to debug - but I don't know if read/write operations eventually will get too slow)